# Role of Melatonin in Circadian Rhythm

Tags: melatonin

Melatonin regulates the wake-sleep cycle by causing drowsiness and lowering body temperature, but which specific chemical pathways lead to this drowsiness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite complicated question, as melatonin has quite a range of effects on the cells. First, melatonin binds to three different melatonin receptors, which are found in a wide variety of tissues or organs including brain and retina, cardiovascular system, liver and gallbladder, intestine, kidney, immune cells, adipocytes, prostate and breast epithelial cells, ovary/granulosa cells, myometrium, and skin.

Two of the receptors a G-protein coupled receptors (GPCR), the MT1 and MT2 receptors. The third is a quinone reductase called QR2.

For more details, see this papers:

- [Melatonin receptors in humans: biological role and clinical
  relevance.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16527442)
- [Melatonin receptors and their regulation: biochemical and structural
  mechanisms.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12628439)

The role of melatonin is pretty broad, see the figure (from this article:"[Melatonin: Nature's most versatile biological signal?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16817850)")

[image]

The receptors transport the outside chemical signal (the melatonin) to the inside and activate (or repress) a number of different signal transduction pathways. See the figure below (taken from [Qiagen](http://www.qiagen.com/products/genes%20and%20pathways/pathway%20details?pwid=288)):

[image]

This includes MAP-Kinase pathways, proteinkinase C, IP3, adenyl cyclase and so on. This is quite complicated and I recommend reading some of the following articles if you are interested in a deeper insight. Finally these signals are transmitted into the nucleus and result in a changed gene regulation/expression.

- [Melatonin receptors, heterodimerization, signal transduction and
  binding sites: what's new?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18493248)
- [Physiological effects of melatonin: role of melatonin receptors and
  signal transduction pathways.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18571301)

Comment: The second picture is beautiful !

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia article on [melatonin receptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melatonin_receptor) (with some modifications) :

> In mammals, melatonin receptors, which are G protein coupled receptors, are found in the brain and some
>   peripheral organs. However, there is considerable variation in the
>   density and location of MT receptor expression between species.
>
> **MT1**
>
> In humans, The MT1 subtype is expressed in the pars tuberalis of the
>   pituitary gland and the suprachiasmatic nuclei of the
>   hypothalamus....This is indicative of its role in circadian and
>   reproductive function.
>
> **MT2**
>
> The MT2 subtype is expressed in the retina. MT2 receptor mRNA has not
>   been detected by in situ hybridization in the rat suprachiasmatic
>   nucleo or pars tubealis. This receptor may have a role in light
>   dependent functions.

Comment: I know this does not tell about the pathway but I suggest you try searching some of the papers cited at the end of the wikipedia article.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed this topic. It is interesting and I will have a look into thi later this evening.